# Rails: Optional lookup fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I am using **collection_select** to provide a list of valid choices for the user. I stored only the **id** from the looked-up table. I then make a call to the looked-up class in the **show** view to retrieve the actual value for the id.

in edit:

```
= f.collection_select :language_id, Language.find(:all, :conditions => ["supported = 't'"]), :id, :language, include_blank: false, :prompt => "Language"
```

in show:

```
%p
  %b Language:
  = Language.find(@article.language_id).language_code
```

This is all working fine unless no choice is made. If the **@article.language_id** field is null, the view cannot load as the **find** fails. Any suggestions on how to ignore null values and leave the field blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `find_by_id` would be an option, as it does not raise an error if the id could not be found.

this issues a call to the database though.

so i would just check the languange_id and provide a default

```
= @article.language_id.nil? ? default : Language.find_by_id(@article.language_id)
```

this could also be moved into the model or a helper, so that it does not clutter your view code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. Simply use `try` to leave nil values:

```
 if @article.try(:language_id) != nil
      @code = Language.find(@article.language_id).language_code
    else
      //default nil
      @code = nil
  end
```

Comment: find raises an error if the ID could not be found, so this wont work

Comment: ok, I updated the code.This should work for you applying conditions.